# DirectX11 Depth values only 0 and 1

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11, depth-buffer

I'm porting my OpenGL Renderer to DirectX. Almost everything work fine, but I have a problem with depth. Everything in 3D is rendering as flat. I've checked Visual Studio Graphics Analyzer and Depth Buffer and State is bind. If I check Depth/Stencil Texture Resource, there are only values 0.f (where something is on screen) and 1.f (where nothing is rendered). OpenGL renderer checked with gDEBugger shows values from 0.f to 1.f and OpenGL is working. I've also checked error codes. Everything returns S_OK. What could I do wrong?

Here is my DepthStencilState creation:

```
                D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_DESC dsDescEn;
                ZeroMemory(&dsDescEn, sizeof(D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_DESC));

                dsDescEn.DepthEnable = TRUE;
                dsDescEn.DepthWriteMask = D3D11_DEPTH_WRITE_MASK_ALL;
                dsDescEn.DepthFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_LESS;

                dsDescEn.StencilEnable = TRUE;
                dsDescEn.StencilReadMask = 0xFF;
                dsDescEn.StencilWriteMask = 0xFF;

                dsDescEn.FrontFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
                dsDescEn.FrontFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_INCR;
                dsDescEn.FrontFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
                dsDescEn.FrontFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;

                dsDescEn.BackFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
                dsDescEn.BackFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_DECR;
                dsDescEn.BackFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
                dsDescEn.BackFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;

                DirectX11Device::getDevice().getDevicePtr()->CreateDepthStencilState(&dsDescEn, &m_dSStateEn);
```

I'm binding State via OMSetDepthStencilState.

```
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC depthStencilDesc;

                    depthStencilDesc.Width = width;
                    depthStencilDesc.Height = height;
                    depthStencilDesc.MipLevels = 1;
                    depthStencilDesc.ArraySize = 1;
                    depthStencilDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
                    depthStencilDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
                    depthStencilDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
                    depthStencilDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
                    depthStencilDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;
                    depthStencilDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
                    depthStencilDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

                    D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC depthStencilViewDesc;
                    ZeroMemory(&depthStencilViewDesc, sizeof(D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC));

                    depthStencilViewDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
                    depthStencilViewDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
                    depthStencilViewDesc.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;

                    DirectX11Device::getDevice().getDevicePtr()->CreateTexture2D(&depthStencilDesc, NULL, &m_stencilDepthBuff);
                    DirectX11Device::getDevice().getDevicePtr()->CreateDepthStencilView(m_stencilDepthBuff, &depthStencilViewDesc, &m_stencilDepthView);
```

Comment: What values are you using for your viewport?

Comment: Maximum is 1.0f and minimum 0.0f. If i change these values, there is nothing rendering and DirectX shows errors in Output Window.

Comment: Looks good. Are you sure that you render with correct depth values? Try to output a specific depth from the pixel shader.

Comment: I've calculated depth as position.z / position.w, and binded as Color in PS. All is black, so depth always is 0. Maybe it's a problem with my Vertex Shader? In Vertex Shader i multiply matrices with float4x4 MVP =  mul(MV, P); and multiply vertex position by calculated matrix with mul(float4(pos.xyz, 1.0f), MVP); Matrices comes from OpenGL and they're converted by transposition and changing signs. Everything look like in OpenGL, but without depth.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution. The problem was matrices multiplication. I moved it to shader from C++ and now it's working without problems.